# Factorizing smooth maps in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions

Dimension $1$ case: Suppose $f,g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ are smooth functions that fixes $0$. If $g'(0)\ne0$, then we can write $f(x)=\phi(x)g(x)$ locally in a neighborhood of $0$. This is simple because we can let $\phi=f/g$ which is smooth at $0$ by Taylor theorem.

I want to generalize this to higher dimension: Suppose Suppose $f,g:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ are smooth maps that fixes $0$, and $\det(Dg)\ne 0$. Can we write

$$f_i(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n\phi_{ij}(x)g_j(x)$$

locally for some smooth functions $\phi_{ij}$ near $0$?

Comment: I suspect this (a) can be reduced to the case where $f(x)=x$ (since we can then multiply by any other function after the fact) and (b) the case $f(x)=x$ should follow from the Inverse Function Theorem.

Comment: I think you mean $g(x)=x$. But yes you are right, now I know how to do it.